# How to pass method to other method as an argument?

Tags: c++

I have two classes with methods:

```
void ClassA::myFunction(void (*fn)() = NULL);
void ClassB::run();
```

And some code

```
ClassA A();
ClassB B();

void runBfn()
{
  B.run();
}

void setup()
{
  A.myFunction( runBFn ); // works
  A.myFunction( [](void){B.run();} ); // works
  A.myFunction( B.run ); // not works
}
```

Why `A.myFunction( B.run );` does not work? Can I make it without declaring separate function ( anonymous or not )?

Comment: just use the lambda version. Alternatively you need to change the signature of `myFunction`.

Comment: But why this happens? Is that because methods are shared in memory between instances of classes, and pointer to method does not contain info about instance?

Comment: @filimonic it is because function pointers and method pointers are two completely different and incompatible types.

Comment: Not an arduino-specific question, BTW.

Answer (score 2):

`myFunction()` takes a pointer to a standalone function, not a pointer to a class method. A non-capturing lambda is implicitly convertible to a function pointer.

You need to either:

1. add an overload of `myFunction()` that takes a method pointer:

```
class ClassB;

class ClassA {
public:
    void myFunction(void (*fn)());
    void myFunction(B &b, void (B::*fn)());
};

class ClassB {
public:
    void run();
};
```

```
void ClassA::myFunction(void (*fn)()) {
    fn();
}

void ClassA::myFunction(B &b, void (B::*fn)()) {
    (b.*fn)();
}

void ClassB::run() {
    ...
}
```

```
ClassA A;
ClassB B;

void runBfn() { B.run(); }

void setup() {
    A.myFunction( runBFn );
    A.myFunction( [](){ B.run(); } );
    A.myFunction( B, &ClassB::run );
}
```

2. add an overload of `myFunction()` that takes an interface that `ClassB` implements:

```
class Runnable {
public:
    virtual void run() = 0;
};

class ClassA {
public:
    void myFunction(void (*fn)());
    void myFunction(Runnable &r);
};

class ClassB : public Runnable {
public:
    void run() override;
};
```

```
void ClassA::myFunction(void (*fn)()) {
    fn();
}

void ClassA::myFunction(Runnable &r) {
    r.run();
}

void ClassB::run() {
    ...
}
```

```
ClassA A;
ClassB B;

void runBfn() { B.run(); }

void setup() {
    A.myFunction( runBFn );
    A.myFunction( [](){ B.run(); } );
    A.myFunction( B );
}
```

3. make `myFunction()` take a `std::function` instead of a function pointer:

```
#include <functional>

class ClassA {
public:
    void myFunction(std::function<void()> fn);
};

class ClassB {
public:
    void run();
};
```

```
void ClassA::myFunction(std::function<void()> fn) {
    fn();
}

void ClassB::run() {
    ...
}
```

```
ClassA A;
ClassB B;

void runBfn() { B.run(); }

void setup() {
    A.myFunction( runBFn );
    A.myFunction( [](){ B.run(); } );
    auto fn = std::bind(&ClassB::run, &B);
    A.myFunction( fn );
}
```

4. make `myFunction()` a template function that can be called with any compatible callable function/object:

```
class ClassA {
public:
    template<typename Callable>
    void myFunction(Callable fn) {
        fn();
    }
};

class ClassB {
public:
    void run();
};
```

```
void ClassB::run() {
    ...
}
```

```
ClassA A;
ClassB B;

void runBfn() { B.run(); }

void setup() {
    A.myFunction( runBFn );
    A.myFunction( [](){ B.run(); } );
    auto fn = std::bind(&ClassB::run, &B);
    A.myFunction( fn );
}
```

Comment: 5. have an interface with this function as parameter

Comment: @Juraj can your elaborate? That sounds like you are just restating OP's question.

Comment: sorry, I meant your point 2. I commented first as `4. have an interface with this function as parameter`. later I saw you added a point but I missed it was exactly that so I re-added the comment with 5.

Answer (score 2):

This is because member function signature is `void (ClassB::*)()`

But you expect as parameter `void (*)()`

I'd suggest you to use `std::function` for such problems:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class ClassB
{
public:
    void print(std::string str) {
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
};

void test_foo(std::function<void(std::string)> foo)
{
    foo("Hello");
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    //...

    ClassB b;
    auto print_f = std::bind(&ClassB::print, b, std::placeholders::_1);
    test_foo(print_f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A lambda is generally preferred over `std::bind()`, eg: `ClassB b; test_foo( [&](std::string str){ b.print(str); } );`

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the function signature:

```
void myFunction2(void (ClassB::*run)(void), ClassB& b){}
```

then call it with:

```
A.myFunction2( &ClassB::run, B);
```

Live on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5HVJcv).

PS.

These are not objects but functions:

```
ClassA A();
ClassB B();
```

you can use this instead:

```
ClassA A{};
ClassB B{};
```